# Qt 5.1.1 Android: How to initialize and show OpenGL window on GUI event?

Tags: android, qt, opengl-es

I need to initialize and show OpenGL window not while application starts but by GUI event like QPushButton::clicked().

I am trying to run the ‘openglwindow’ Qt 5.1.1 example on Android 4.0.4 Samsung Galaxy Tab 2. The original project builds and runs correctly. I can see a rotating triangle.

Then I try to do TriangleWindow.show() by event not in main() function but in 'CMainWindow::SelectSecondPage()' slot. Expose event passes successfully but the application crashes in OpenGLWindow::renderNow() function on initializeOpenGLFunctions().

How can I initialize and show OpenGLWindow on event correctly?

```
CMainWindow::CMainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setSamples(16);

m_pTriangleWindow = new TriangleWindow;
m_pTriangleWindow->setFormat(format);

m_pTriangleWindow->resize(640, 480);
m_pTriangleWindow->setPosition(5000, 5000);

m_pWidgetStack = new QStackedWidget(this);

QWidget*        pFirstPage  = new QWidget(m_pWidgetStack);
QPushButton*    pPushButton = new QPushButton("Start Triangle window", m_pWidgetStack);
QVBoxLayout*    pLayout     = new QVBoxLayout;

connect(pPushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(SelectSecondPage()));

pLayout->addStretch();
pLayout->addWidget(pPushButton);
pLayout->addStretch();

pFirstPage->setLayout(pLayout);
m_pWidgetStack->addWidget(pFirstPage);

m_pSecondPage = new QWidget(m_pWidgetStack);
m_pWidgetStack->addWidget(m_pSecondPage);

setCentralWidget(m_pWidgetStack);
m_pWidgetStack->setCurrentIndex(0);
}

void CMainWindow::SelectSecondPage()
{
m_pWidgetStack->setCurrentIndex(1);

m_pTriangleWindow->show();
m_pTriangleWindow->setAnimating(true);
}
```

Application output:

```
W/Qt      (27127): ../src/androidjnimain.cpp:449 (jboolean startQtApplication(JNIEnv*, jobject, jstring, jstring)): Can't set environment "" 
W/Qt      (27127): kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp:412 (QCoreApplicationPrivate::QCoreApplicationPrivate(int&, char**, uint)): WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
D/libEGL  (27127): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  (27127): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
D/libEGL  (27127): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
W/dalvikvm(27127): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNativeInputConnection'
W/dalvikvm(27127): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtExtractedText'
D/Qt      (27127): ../OpenGLWindow/openglwindow.cpp:118 (virtual void OpenGLWindow::exposeEvent(QExposeEvent*)): exposeEvent passed 
E/libEGL  (27127): eglMakeCurrent:674 error 3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/Qt      (27127): eglconvenience/qeglplatformcontext.cpp:111 (virtual bool QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent(QPlatformSurface*)): QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent: eglError: 3009, this: 0x2098190 
W/Qt      (27127):
```

Comment: As far as I know Qt currently (Qt5.1) has some issues with multiple top level windows and especially with OpenGL windows. As I heard OpenGL window can only be fullscreen so maybe your problem has something to do with that. I would suggest you to stick to only one top level window as its naturally for Android. If you want to implement some GUI + OpenGL render, you can try QQuickView + QML scene for GUI and Opengl render on the same QQuickView, see openglunderqml example which comes with Qt